# using openmp in windows R, does rtools support openmp?

Tags: c++, windows, r, openmp

I got lots of error messages when trying to use openmp in a c++ code for building my R package on windows 7:

```
c:/rtools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/libgomp.a(parallel.o):(.text+0x19): undefined      reference to `_imp__pthread_getspecific'
c:/rtools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/libgomp.a(parallel.o):(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_lock'
c:/rtools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/libgomp.a(env.o):(.text+0x510): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_init'

...
```

Is Rtools not supporting openmp? 
Does anyone know how to use openmp in windows R packages please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, per discussions on the [R-devel mailing list](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Missing-libpthread-in-RTools-td2997693.html).  It also came up on the [Rcpp-devel list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rcpp/1180).

R itself does not use OpenMP on Windows, so there is not support in Rtools.  On other OSs R does  of course have OpenMP support.

Comment: @Joshua: Sort of a lame dig, I have plenty of OpenMP applications on Windows and *nix.

Comment: Also mentioned in the useful section 'OpenMP support' in 'Writing R Extensions'

Comment: Now openmp is supported on Windows, what should we do regarding such outdated answers?

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: Be nice to get an update of this comment for 2014 R3.1X

Answer (score 12):

In 2015, `Rtools` has `openmp` support under Windows, which plays nicely with `Rcpp`. Here is a simple example creating a `squares` function for numeric vectors:

```
// src/example.cpp

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <omp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector squares (Rcpp::NumericVector data)
{
  Rcpp::NumericVector result(data.size());
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    Rcpp::Rcout << omp_get_num_threads() << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
      result[i] = data[i] * data[i];
    }

  }
  return result;
}
```

We also need to create `src/Makevars.win` with the `openmp` compilation flags. In this example, the sample `src/Makevars` will work on linux:

```
# src/Makevars.win

PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 3):

By reference to [these posts](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/gomp-library-with-Rtools212-td3050582.html) (R-devel mailing list), I tried to use OpenMP in windows R packages by using [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/).
It seems to run right.

But I recommend to use officially supported OSs.
I don't know what problems will happen.