# Error with R package for Windows using openmp

Tags: r, openmp, ld, cran

I did as the R extension documentation to set

```
PKG_CFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
```

in the **src/Makevars** file.

On linux it builds fine while on windows it gets various errors like:

```
undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
undefined reference to `GOMP_barrier'
```

From the documentation I feel openmp is supported on Windows now. Is it right? How to solve the errors if it is supported by official Rtools?

An old post related: [using openmp in windows R, does rtools support openmp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228924/using-openmp-in-windows-r-does-rtools-support-openmp) , which says openmp not supported on windows at that time.

Comment: `GOMP_barrier` is a function in the GCC OpenMP runtime library. If the package build uses GCC to also link the object files then the `-fopenmp` option should be present at link time. Otherwise the objects have to be explicitly linked against `libgomp` via the `-lgomp` option.

Comment: What compiler are you building R with on Windows?

Comment: With the Rtools packaged version, GCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually caused by UTF-8 BOM in the **src/Makevars.win** file, removing BOM fixed it for me.